# subprocess.check_output doesnt work in python 3, but works in python 2.7

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I have the following code, which gave me correct results python 2.7, but as soon as I have ported to python 3, the code doesnt work as expected. I can see correct results in the variable `submodule_commit`, but they are like `b'xxxxxxx\nyyyyyyy'` and the split doesnt work anymore. 
I dont understand, wht is going wrong here. 
My expectations is a list with submodules.

```
command = "git submodule status | awk '{print $1}'"
submodule_commit = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
submodule_commit = submodule_commit.split('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

I converted the byte string into normal string and it works now.

```
command = "git submodule status | awk '{print $1}'"
submodule_commit = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
submodule_commit = str(submodule_commit, 'utf-8')
submodule_commit = submodule_commit.split('\n')
```

Comment: You can also pass the encoding directly to the `check_output` command, then it will return a `str`, e.g. `subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, encoding='utf-8')`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing  `submodule_commit.split(b'\n')` instead. `b'xxxxxxx\nyyyyyyy'` is a byte-string and, your splitting method should also taken an input a byte-string. To convert `'\n'` into a byte-string, you write `b'\n'` instead. I Let me know if it works. :)